# Is there a way to type-cast a Scala object using reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection

I am using reflection to create Scala objects.  I don't have ready access to 'T', to type-cast an object like one normally would like this:

```
def makeOne[T](o:Object) = o.asInstanceOf[T]
```

I do have a universe.Type tho.  Earlier in my processing I do something like this:

```
def analyze[T](o:Object)(implicit tt:TypeTag[T]) = {...}
```

I save tt.tpe, so much later when I'm creating an object of type T, I've lost the 'T' but I still retain tt.tpe.

Is there any way I can use this universe.Type to type-cast my object without having to need 'T', as in .asInstanceOf[T]?

(BTW, I can create the object using reflection just fine...Its just that the created object doesn't know its type. It's just thinks its an Any.)

Comment: The major problem you have is, `asInstanceOf` is a compile-time construct, but you're using run time reflection.

Comment: If you don't know the type you want to cast to at compile time then what is the use of casting?

Comment: You should keep the `T` around - I can't think of a case where you could still have `tt` but can't pass in `T`. Also, this sounds a bit like an XY problem...

Answer (score 1):

Shapeless has a facility to figure out if a cast is reasonable.

```
scala> import shapeless._, Typeable._
import shapeless._
import Typeable._

scala> class C
defined class C

scala> val c: AnyRef = new C
c: AnyRef = C@5e1e2bb6

scala> implicitly[Typeable[C]]
res0: shapeless.Typeable[C] = Typeable[C]

scala> res0.cast(c)
res1: Option[C] = Some(C@5e1e2bb6)

scala> res0.cast("nope")
res2: Option[C] = None

scala> val vs: AnyRef = List(1,2,3)
vs: AnyRef = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> implicitly[Typeable[List[Int]]].cast(vs)
res3: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))

scala> implicitly[Typeable[List[String]]].cast(vs)
res4: Option[List[String]] = None
```

I see the Typeable macro just uses the WeakTypeTag you get inside a macro. Certainly you could pass around a Typeable as a representation of the type you want back.